# POSTGRESQL foreign key like constraint

Tags: postgresql

I have tableA called `Order`

It has a PK  **id**  several columns and a bool column named `active` and a column **tableid**. Two orders cant be active at the same time for a **tableid** that is ensured with a two column unique contraint (&& active=true) that works like an index and finding active orders is pretty fast.
The problem is that there is another table **orderitems**. I want active to be true unless all orderitems for the order-id are marked as paid=true..
Using serialization transactions this can be achieved i think in payment code by setting an update query if all items are  paid. I think that this wont work always.Because if they run concurrently they might both see that there are unpaid items(due to old snapshot) but when commit they would pay all items,but not update active column.(different) .
Adding new items and payment transaction tries to set active=false wont be a problem with serial transactions because one of them would fail..
I think triggers are a solution but i dont know what to do exactly.. Thank you for reading

Comment: Right idea....trigger functions would be able to handle this.   Is orderitems updated to be set as paid = true?  Or is it an insert?   use table funks in any case :   Postgres documentation... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Spell check changed funcs to funks.  ha.  use table funks = use trigger funcs.

Comment: The question is: can this be done *without* triggers? To the OP: could you please add the relevant table definitions, including keys and constraints? That could save some people some typing...

Comment: @wildplasser In 9.1 using its new true `SERIALIZABLE` mode I think it might be possible if you're meticulous about always doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the Order when `INSERT`ing a new order item. You have to do the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` because there's still no predicate locking; it can't know that the newly inserted order item breaks serializability when another transaction is looking at other orderitems with the same order ID. For that reason, I'd recommend doing it in a trigger.

Comment: In 9.1 they say that there is predicate locking. Testing with updates worked but i havent tested with inserts

Comment: Personally, I don't like triggers. They can hide real flaws of the the data model or of the ability to create a correct data model. Besides, they are *invisible* to the schema. I like good, "pure" data models. Triggers are Betty Boop on steroids. Avoid them, while you can. Besides: (to the OP)show me the table definitions.

Comment: @wildplasser i'll update.In official documentation the solution for this is a trigger but seems gay to me. I think that i can use serializable transacations to esneure that they are updated..

Comment: I don't like the "orderitems" part. Is it kind of a domain? Does the orders have a FK to it? Maybe the intended constraint is only business-logic?

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is add an `AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE FOR EACH ROW` trigger on `orderitems` that determines whether `Order.active` should be changed. You'll have to do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the `Order` row that owns those `orderitems` otherwise you'll risk concurrent runs of the trigger racing against each other and doing out-of-order updates.

Presuming `orderitems` has a field `order_id` that is your foreign key reference to `Order.id`, try something like the (untested, general example only) code following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION orderitems_order_active_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  _old_active BOOLEAN;
  _new_active BOOLEAN;
  _order_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = 'INSERT' THEN
    _order_id = NEW.order_id;
  ELIF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN
    _order_id = NEW.order_id;
  ELIF tg_op = 'DELETE' THEN
    _order_id = OLD.order_id;
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected trigger operation %',tg_op;
  END IF;
  -- Lock against concurrent trigger runs and other changes in the parent record while
  -- obtaining the current value of `active`
  SELECT INTO _old_active Order.active FROM Order WHERE Order.id = _order_id FOR UPDATE;
  -- Now figure out whether the order should be active. We'll say that if there are
  -- more than zero unpaid order items found we'll treat it as active.
  _new_active = EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM orderitems WHERE orderitems.order_id = _order_id AND orderitems.paid='f');
  -- If the active state has flipped, update the order.
  IF _old_active IS DISTINCT FROM _new_active THEN
    UPDATE Order SET active = _new_active WHERE Order.id = _order_id;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER orderitems_ensure_active_correct AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
ON orderitems FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE orderitems_order_active_trigger();
```